# how to protect POST data in PHP that can be manipulated in the url

Tags: php, angularjs

I have an function with angular doing this:

```
$http({
method:"post",
url:"savedata.php",
data:$.param($scope.cat),
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(function(data){
```

and in savedata.php I do this:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
```

that's fine and I can work with it. But if you do this in the browser: savedata.php?name=dog it will process the data.

How can I avoid this? How can I only allow php to process data sent from the angular function, and not from the browser with the url.
Or are there better ways of working like this?
I'm trying to let savedata.php function as an restfull API, and I don't want it to be meddled with except from my own functions.

Comment: use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` is not populated from the URL query string.  If this is happening, you have an error in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Do it with default Content-Type which is application/json.

You will get application/json data on PHP side in php input.

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

print_r($post);
```